# Application page cant know that am the admin?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tornado

[seached and found that /me/accounts/](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)  is no more available, in the past i used it, so i posted on a page's application without any problem, using [that Gist](http://tornadogists.org/5647185/),

But i deleted that application and tried to add another new one, when changed the code to:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request("/me/applications/developer/", self._on_accounts, access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])

    def _on_accounts(self, account):
        if account is None:
            # Session may have expired
            print "on accounts failed"
            sys.exit()

        print "here we go!"
        print account # this will return me a json
        for acc in account["data"]:
            if acc["id"] == "157547381099830":
                self.facebook_request("/157547381099830/feed", post_args={"message":"hi there!", "link": "http://www.example.com"}, access_token=self.current_user["access_token"], callback=self.async_callback(self._on_page_post))
```

what i can to do, is only post on my wall *(changing `self.facebook_request("/157547381099830/feed"...` by `self.facebook_request("/me/feed"...` 
)*
I entered to the page, and Facebook knows that am the admin, but if i use the python code, it will publish the stream a normal user!

Edit: It seems that the  problem is kind of new Facebook rules? when switch to my name, i cant publish on the wall, even if i'm the admin?

In the management setting, it is written:

> Manager
>   Abdelouahab can manage admin roles, send messages and create posts as the Page, create ads, and view insights.

But, it seems it is not the case, because when i choose:

**You are posting, commenting, and liking as Abdelouahab Abdenour Aliane — Change to Essog Community** then i can post, only if i switch to **Essog Community** (because i blocked external users from posting on the wall).

Update: added `manage_pages` to the scope, and even this did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer:

1. Dident use `manage_pages` in the first time, so i used the page token!
2. [i must get the page access token and not the user token!](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current user, **you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token commonly used for reading Graph API objects**.

(deleted and begin a new page)

this will work:

```
for acc in account["data"]:
    if acc["id"] == "345632575539519":
        print acc["access_token"]
        self.facebook_request("/345632575539519/feed", post_args={"message":"hello", "link": "http://www.example.com"}, access_token=acc["access_token"], callback=self.async_callback(self._on_page_post))
```